# Fill nullable properties with GenFu

Tags: c#, mocking

I have a class like this:

```
public class Thing
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

And I configured like this:

```
A.Configure<Thing>()
    .Fill(x => x.Id)
    .Fill(x => x.Timestamp);
```

but when I create a list with `var things = A.ListOf<Thing>(50);`, all of them have Id and Timestamp as null

(I'm using it in a .NET framework 4.6.2 project)

What I'm missing? How can I force nullable properties to be filled?

Comment: According to these tests found on the repo it should work https://github.com/MisterJames/GenFu/blob/master/tests/GenFu.Tests/When_filling_nullables.cs Still reviewing to see why the list is not working

Comment: I created a test and was able to reproduce the problem. After reviewing the repo and [this commit](https://github.com/MisterJames/GenFu/commit/3297e06a31c23721e5c5e212eaa04b6c20a23617), I believe that it should work given what functionality was added. My suspicion is that the code in the repo probably was not pushed to Nuget as yet. so that functionality is not in the referenced code you are using.

Comment: thanks. i hope they'll push a new version soon

Comment: What version of GenFu are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.4.1